# How to use dns.lookup() within POST method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, url

I work on the URL shortener project. I want to use dns.lookup method. It works for me while using it separately. Once I use it within POST method, it does not work anymore and returns false even though an address is valid. Could you help me with it? Thank you!
Here is the whole project: https://url-shortener-lm.glitch.me
Here is the problem code:

```js
app.post('/api/shorturl/new', (req, res, next) => {
  var originalURL = req.body.url;
  dns.lookup(originalURL, (err, address, family) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        originalURL: originalURL,
        shortenedURL: "Invalid URL"
      });
    } else {
      var shortenedURL = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000).toString();

      var data = new Model({
        originalURL: originalURL,
        shortenedURL: shortenedURL
      });

      data.save(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          return console.error(err);
        }
      });

      res.json({
        originalURL: originalURL,
        shortenedURL: shortenedURL
      })
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: Very well presented question.  I see so many questions from fairly new users here on stack overflow that need lots of clarification in order to understand what the question is about so I applaud you for posting such a clear question!  You stated the problem clearly, you distilled the problem down to the relevant code, you included that code and formatted it appropriately and you even included a link to the rest of the project in case any other code was involved.  Bravo.  I've provided an answer below that will hopefully help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dns.lookup()` expects you to pass it only a hostname such as `www.google.com`, not a url.  You can see a code example in the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookup_hostname_options_callback) where it just passes `"example.com"`.

You can parse the hostname out of the url.  You can either use the original node.js `url` parsing capabilities or the newer standard URL object (that is common to both browser and node.js).  I show the newer URL object here:

```
const URL = require('url').URL;

app.post('/api/shorturl/new', (req, res, next) => {

  const originalURL = req.body.url;
  const urlObject = new URL(originalURL);

  dns.lookup(urlObject.hostname, (err, address, family) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        originalURL: originalURL,
        shortenedURL: "Invalid URL"
      });
    } else {
      var shortenedURL = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000).toString();

      var data = new Model({
        originalURL: originalURL,
        shortenedURL: shortenedURL
      });

      data.save(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          return console.error(err);
        }
      });

      res.json({
        originalURL: originalURL,
        shortenedURL: shortenedURL
      })
    };
  });
});
```

---

To see what the URL object is capable of parsing out of a URL such as:

http://www.example.com:3000/somePath/somePage.html

Here's a simple test app and the output that it delivers:

```
const {URL} = require('url');

let originalURL = "http://www.example.com:3000/somePath/somePage.html"
const urlObject = new URL(originalURL);

console.log(urlObject.hostname);
console.log(urlObject);
```

That shows this output:

```
www.example.com
URL {
  href: 'http://www.example.com:3000/somePath/somePage.html',
  origin: 'http://www.example.com:3000',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'www.example.com:3000',
  hostname: 'www.example.com',
  port: '3000',
  pathname: '/somePath/somePage.html',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: ''
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You made my day. I am happy that I presented the question in the right format and even happier that I solved my problem and learned something new today. Thank YOU!